# Template code for infinite scroll recycler view with mvp, dagger 2 and RxJava

Tags: android, mvp, rx-java, android-recyclerview, dagger-2

Is there a template code for creating a list of feeds with recycler view with infinite scrolling and pull to refresh using MVP architechture, Dagger 2 and RxJava?

I already went through many blogs about dagger 2 and mvp and the examples i found was very basic like showing some feeds in simple listview but i need to implement infinite scrolling, pull to refresh and also error handling.

I couldnt get the whole picture to get this thing done using mvp, dagger 2 and RxJava cuz i just started with these things.

Comment: cannot you just do that **without**  Dagger 2 and RxJava ?

Comment: I already did that but i am building a update for my app and i want to architect it properly so i am trying to use dagger and rxjava

Comment: so **without** Dagger 2 and RxJava is not made properly? i cannot follow your ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Repository [MvpCleanArchitecture](https://github.com/glomadrian/MvpCleanArchitecture) is an example of usage:

- MVP architechture
- <s>Dagger 2</s> - Dagger 1.9 (I think this is not very important)
- Infinite scroll
- <s>RxJava</s>
  **And also:**
- Retrofit
- ButterKnife
- Parceler
- Picasso

This project is best fit your description, but, *without **RxJava***.

If you need to architect your app using RxJava, you can checkout this repositories:

- [rx-android-architecture](https://github.com/tehmou/rx-android-architecture)
- [android-best-practices](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices)
- [rex-weather](https://github.com/vyshane/rex-weather)

More repositories with MVP archetecture you can find [here](https://github.com/AlexanderGarmash/Interesting-Android-repositories#android-app-architecture-repositories)